# Is there a way to include knitr documents in a LaTeX document?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I think the question as stated maybe ambiguous, so let me describe my use case.

I am working on a document that is primarily ordinary English text edited in a LaTeX editor (Texpad in my case), but in which I'd like to include material I've developed in knitr-based `.Rnw` file.

One way to do this is to turn the parent document into a `knitr` document and have the `R`-related stuff as child documents. While I have done this before, there are a few downsides:

1. Even when LaTeX editors support knitr, their support makes working with `.Rnw` files much clunkier than "pure" LaTeX (`.tex`) files.
2. Co-authors may not want to use `R` or `knitr`.

One approach that seems to work, while being a bit clunky, is to separately `knit` the `.Rnw` files and `\input{}` the resulting `.tex` files. (One could even have a separate `.Rnw` parent for compiling the `knitr` documents more easily as they are worked on.)

To illustrate this idea, I made a small GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/iangow/knitr_grandchildren).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest, that you put the knitr-generated preamble in your main-tex file into a sub-file to and import it. I think knitr should create a package for that but it doesn't. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @Yihui (private correspondence): "Sorry, but no. The approach that you mentioned in the post is the only thing I can think of."